# Problems when connecting to a SQL Server 2000 when the name has a trailing space

Tags: connection, sql-server

We have two application servers that a configured quite similarly, however there is a discrepancy between them when they attempt to connect to a server name with a space appended to the end.

So, for exnmple, given the server name 'MySQLServer' (without quotes):

- Machine 1 connects to MySQLServer with the names 'MySQLServer' and
  'MyServer '
- Machine 2 connects to MySQLServer with the name 'MySQLServer' but not
  'MyServer '

Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Trim the space and go on.

Comment: How are you connecting?

Comment: @Maliq: Yes, that would fix it, however I'm wondering why its different on the two servers

Comment: @GregD: I'm connecting:Simply through the Query Analyser/Enterprise Manager tool login dialog

Answer (score 1):

Check the alias setup on each application server.

You should use the program named "Client network utility" into MSSQL group.

Comment: Nothing indicative in here. Both are identical.

Comment: DNS settings? Check also c:\windir\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.